# Redefine font used in \mathit

Tags: fonts, math-mode, libertine

I am using the `libertine` package with `pdflatex`.
For maths I use the Computer Modern font.
In formulas I need longer variable names and to do get the spacing right I use `\mathit`.
The font used is however Computer Modern which is fine for one-letter variables but looks a bit odd for longer ones (the short and long variables are used for semantically different objects so a difference in font should not be too upsetting).
What is the correct way of globally redefining the font set by `\mathit`?
Right now I have

```
\renewcommand{\mathit}[1]{\text{\itshape #1}}
```

which looks like a hack. Is there a better way? Which unwanted side-effects could my solution cause?

Comment: Using Computer Modern for math with Libertine as main text font can take you before the Spanish Inquisition and you could be sentenced to the comfy chair. Be advised.

Comment: why not simply use `\textit`

Comment: I would (a) define a macro named (say) `\V`, as `\newcommand\V[1]{\textit{#1}}`, in the preamble and (b) write `\V{VarName1}`, `\V{VarName2}`, etc in the body of the document.

Comment: I'd recommend `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Computer Modern for math with Libertine as main text font can take you before the Spanish Inquisition and you could be sentenced to the comfy chair. Be advised. `;-)`

You can do much better: the package `newtxmath` accepts the option `libertine` and provides math symbols that go along well with Linux Libertine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\newcommand{\V}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text before a silly formula $\sin x+\V{VarA}-\V{VarB}=\cos t$
and some text after it.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you compare it with the output from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{libertine}

\newcommand{\V}[1]{\textnormal{\itshape#1}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text before a silly formula $\sin x+\V{VarA}-\V{VarB}=\cos t$
and some text after it.

\end{document}
```

you'll see what I mean in my first paragraph.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph. +1 for a fine answer. -1 for enablement :P

Comment: @egreg yes I see why mixing the two styles in a formula is dreadful. What I was aiming for was using symbols (e.g. `\to`, `=`, `\subseteq`...) and as variables only `\V{...}` names. If I use CM only then I get a suboptimal mix of fonts when I mention `\V` names in the main text...but I do not like libertine as a math font for its thickness and kerning...